# how to return result of select while trying a safe generic stored procedure using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-injection

I was checking a proper way for querying database via using parameterized command
and still be able to pull a query that will match any table as a generic SP.

This sql sp seems without potentially opening up a hole for SQL injection
and do correct me if I am wrong this is safe...

But here the question is, using `sp_executesql` (seems to be the key element for being safe) does not return the SELECT results.

How could I alter that stored procedure to return the value
(and not 'ruining' its safety)

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SafeSqlSP_SelectGivenTableWithOptionalColFilter] 
    @columnList varchar(75) ='*',
    @tableName sysname ,
    @ColNameAsFilter1 varchar(75) ='',
    @ColNameAsFilter2 varchar(75) ='',
    @ColFilter1VAL varchar(75)='',
    @ColFilter2VAL varchar(75)=''       
    AS
            BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(1000)
        if( @ColNameAsFilter2!='' AND @ColNameAsFilter1!='')
            begin
                SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@columnList) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) +' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@ColNameAsFilter1) +' = @ColFilter1VAL AND ' + QUOTENAME(@ColNameAsFilter2) +' = @ColFilter2VAL'
                EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand,
                N'@ColFilter1VAL nvarchar(75), @ColFilter2VAL nvarchar(75)', @ColFilter1VAL= @ColFilter1VAL, @ColFilter2VAL = @ColFilter2VAL
            end
        else if( @ColNameAsFilter1!='' AND @ColNameAsFilter2='') 
            begin
                SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@columnList) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) +' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@ColNameAsFilter1) +' = @ColFilter1VAL'
                EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand,
                N'@ColFilter1VAL nvarchar(75)', @ColFilter1VAL= @ColFilter1VAL
            end
        else if( @ColNameAsFilter1='' AND @ColNameAsFilter2='') 
            begin
                SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@columnList) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)
                EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
            end
    END
```

Comment: It doesn't look safe against SQL injection. You're putting together arbitrary strings without even using `QUOTENAME`. [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) may still surprise you.

Comment: @HABO got it quickly from here (: - http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=117804

Comment: @HABO ... i have updated my code For Your inspection thanks for you help. did i miss any more places to wrap any more parameters or i got it right this time ? so is there a proper way to return a big result such multiple columns and multiple rows as a return value / output or it is different from a normal `select * from` as a result ...

Comment: Did you have a look at what `QuoteName( 'ColumnA, ColumnB' )` does?

Comment: @HABO sorry , did not have a chance to debug / print it ... so i guess i need to "DROP" that ridicules idea of "a Bulletproof Universal Table Select stored procedure" (butsp)

Comment: @HABO i just had an idea - make that `sp_executesql @sqlCommand` to be bulked straight into a #tmp table then Select * from #tmp (if its cool) then what would be the syntax ?

Comment: @HABO forgot about your comment about quating coma separated cols... so whats the verdict ? keep on dreaming ?

Comment: It appears that you always intend to use valid table and column names. You could validate them against the [Information Schema Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx). You still have to parse the column list and validate each column name. It often helps to tag SQL questions with the specific version(s) involved, e.g. `sql-server-2008`, since the features vary considerably.

Comment: @HABO 2012 is my current server version sorry about that

Comment: @HABO in part it also depends on how the data is coming in.  From what I can see the values that are being constructed as part of the string would probably be coming in from an application and don't have the same level of concern for SQL Injection.  The values that are parameterized are the ones that would be coming in from outside data and are the biggest concern.  The SP would have to be used properly, but that's always the case with these things.  All that being said I've been known to miss things before so please correct me if you feel I'm wrong.

Comment: @KennethFisher - Having only a _little_ SQL injection is like having a touch of bubonic plague. The (first) calling application might provide flawless parameters. After a little maintenance, a couple of quick hacks, and a little borrowing of code, who knows what will get passed in. Have a look at the answer I posted for some ideas on input validation and parameter handling.

Comment: @HABO I agree about the "little SQL injection", however my point is that the application developer is also responsible for protecting against it.  And based on the original post it looks like something that should be joint work between a developer and the DBA.  That being said I REALLY like the way you handled columnNames, I didn't think of splitting up the list.  If you don't object I'd like to add that to my implementation.

Comment: @KennethFisher - Sure, the application developer should know all of the tables and views in the appropriate schema and, whenever a schema change occurs, update all of their code to prevent bad things. `@TableName = Salaries`? I'll add a filter for that. re: Borrowing code: [Steal From Your Friends](http://www.computerhistory.org/revolution/mainframe-computers/7/172/697).

Comment: @HABO Fair point.  I still think that the developers need to be as responsible as the DBAs but that is a best case and we should be as careful as possible.

Comment: imo it should return data, you should double check where it is failing. Replace the whole thing with less code to test the concept.

Comment: @eglasius funny it appears it was good exept for when i changed the columnsList to be quated so i guess it is not ..was not good enough because if it wasn't quated it did initially suppose to return value (i suppose it did ), **BUT** we musn't forget the issue of quating the passed values, as i underend it helps with safety , so even if i did accomplish my task i would still dubble check it via posting it to 'inspection' here .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have so far.  With the exception of columnNames (which I'll get to in a sec) I've tested each of the columns that is not paramaterized using sp_executesql.

I'm not entirely pleased with the way I ended up testing columnNames but I don't think this is truly a problem.  First of all I would expect columnList to be coming in from an application, not a user.  A user should not know enough about the structure of your database to be filling in the first 7 parameters and a developer has far more risks that SQL Injection.  That being said the only SQL injection I could think of that would work given where columnList is placed would have to contain the word "FROM" with a space on either side of it.  So I tested for that and raised an error if it occurs.  This would be a problem if you happen to have a column named "This column is FROM somewhere else", but let's hope you don't.

Just a note.  I used the `sys.all_objects` and `sys.all_columns` system views for my tests in case system tables were queried by the procedure.  If you change them to the more commonly used `sys.objects` and `sys.columns` the stored procedure will not work for system views.

EDIT: I added a test on columnList to check for a semicolon.  I realized something along the lines of `'''abc''; print ''test''; select * '` would be a problem.

EDIT2: I've updated the procedure to handle the column list better.  Thanks @HABO!.  I've also added code to handle if values were pre `QUOTENAME`ed with []s, "s or 's, and some common formats for * in the column list.  I'm using the splitter function that @HABO has listed, so I'm not listing it here.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SafeSqlSP_SelectGivenTableWithOptionalColFilter] 
    @columnList nvarchar(max) ='*',
    @tableSchema sysname ,
    @tableName sysname ,
    @ColNameAsFilter1 nvarchar(255) ='',
    @ColNameAsFilter2 nvarchar(255) ='',
    @ColFilter1VAL nvarchar(max)='',
    @ColFilter2VAL nvarchar(max)=''       
    AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --====================================================
    -- Set default values
    IF ISNULL(@tableSchema,'') = ''
        SET @tableSchema = 'dbo'
    ELSE
        SET @tableSchema = LTRIM(RTRIM(@tableSchema))

    IF ISNULL(@columnList,'') = ''
        SET @columnList = '*'

    SET @tableName = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@tableName)),'')
    SET @ColNameAsFilter1 = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ColNameAsFilter1)),'')
    SET @ColNameAsFilter2 = ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(@ColNameAsFilter2)),'')
    SET @ColFilter1VAL = ISNULL(@ColFilter1VAL,'')
    SET @ColFilter2VAL = ISNULL(@ColFilter2VAL,'')

    --====================================================
    -- Remove probably QUOTENAMEs from @tableSchema and @tableName before testing them
    SET @tableSchema = CASE WHEN LEFT(@tableSchema,1) = '[' AND RIGHT(@tableSchema,1) = ']'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@tableSchema,']]',']'),2,LEN(REPLACE(@tableSchema,']]',']'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(@tableSchema,1) = '"' AND RIGHT(@tableSchema,1) = '"'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@tableSchema,'""','"'),2,LEN(REPLACE(@tableSchema,'""','"'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(@tableSchema,1) = '''' AND RIGHT(@tableSchema,1) = ''''
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@tableSchema,'''''',''''),2,LEN(REPLACE(@tableSchema,'''''',''''))-2)
                        ELSE @tableSchema END

    SET @tableName = CASE WHEN LEFT(@tableName,1) = '[' AND RIGHT(@tableName,1) = ']'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@tableName,']]',']'),2,LEN(REPLACE(@tableName,']]',']'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(@tableName,1) = '"' AND RIGHT(@tableName,1) = '"'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@tableName,'""','"'),2,LEN(REPLACE(@tableName,'""','"'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(@tableName,1) = '''' AND RIGHT(@tableName,1) = ''''
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@tableName,'''''',''''),2,LEN(REPLACE(@tableName,'''''',''''))-2)
                        ELSE @tableName END

    --====================================================
    -- Test to make sure the schema.table exists
    IF NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM sys.all_objects
                    JOIN sys.schemas
                        ON sys.all_objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
                    WHERE sys.all_objects.name = @tableName
                      AND sys.schemas.name = @tableSchema
                      AND sys.all_objects.[TYPE] IN ('S','U','V')
                    )
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'Table %s.%s does not exist.',
                        16,
                        1,
                        @tableSchema,
                        @tableName)
            RETURN
        END

    --====================================================
    -- Test to make sure all of the comma delimited values 
    -- are valid columns for schema.table

    -- Create and populate a list of columns from columnlist
    DECLARE @ColumnListTable TABLE (Item varchar(255))

    INSERT INTO @ColumnListTable
    SELECT Item
    FROM dbo.SplitCSL(@columnList)

    -- Remove any extra spaces
    UPDATE @ColumnListTable SET Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(Item))
    -- "Fix" any * formats to a single format of [schema].[tablename].*
    UPDATE @ColumnListTable SET Item = CASE WHEN Item IN (

                @tableName + '.*',  @tableName + '.[*]', 
                '[' + @tableName + '].*', '[' + @tableName + '].[*]',

                @tableSchema + '.' + @tableName + '.*',  @tableSchema + '.' + @tableName + '.[*]', 
                @tableSchema + '.' + '[' + @tableName + '].*', @tableSchema + '.' + '[' + @tableName + '].[*]',

                '[' + @tableSchema + '].' + @tableName + '.*',  '[' + @tableSchema + '].' + @tableName + '.[*]', 
                '[' + @tableSchema + '].' + '[' + @tableName + '].*', '[' + @tableSchema + '].' + '[' + @tableName + '].[*]'
            ) 
            THEN '[' + @tableSchema + '].' + '[' + @tableName + '].*'
            WHEN Item IN ('*','[*]') THEN '*'
            ELSE Item END

    --====================================================
    -- Remove probably QUOTENAMEs from columns in column list before testing them
    UPDATE @ColumnListTable SET Item = 
                        CASE WHEN LEFT(Item,1) = '[' AND RIGHT(Item,1) = ']'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(Item,']]',']'),2,LEN(REPLACE(Item,']]',']'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(Item,1) = '"' AND RIGHT(Item,1) = '"'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(Item,'""','"'),2,LEN(REPLACE(Item,'""','"'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(Item,1) = '''' AND RIGHT(Item,1) = ''''
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(Item,'''''',''''),2,LEN(REPLACE(Item,'''''',''''))-2)
                        ELSE Item END

    -- Check for invalid column names
    DECLARE @ColumnListFailures AS varchar(max)
    SET @ColumnListFailures = ''

    SELECT @ColumnListFailures = STUFF((    
        SELECT ', ' + Item
        FROM @ColumnListTable
        WHERE Item NOT IN (SELECT name
                            FROM sys.all_columns
                            WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableSchema+'.'+@tableName))
          AND Item <> '[' + @tableSchema + '].' + '[' + @tableName + '].*'
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,2, '')

    IF LEN(@ColumnListFailures) > 0
    BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'Table %s.%s does not have columns %s that are listed in the columnList parameter.',
                        16,
                        1,
                        @tableSchema,
                        @tableName,
                        @ColumnListFailures)
            RETURN
    END

    -- QUOTENAME each of the column names and re-create @ColumnList
    SELECT @ColumnList = STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + CASE WHEN Item = '[' + @tableSchema + '].' + '[' + @tableName + '].*' THEN Item 
                ELSE QUOTENAME(Item) END
        FROM @ColumnListTable
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,2, '')


    --====================================================
    -- Remove probably QUOTENAMEs from first and second column filters before testing them
    SET @ColNameAsFilter1 = CASE WHEN LEFT(@ColNameAsFilter1,1) = '[' AND RIGHT(@ColNameAsFilter1,1) = ']'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter1,']]',']'),2,LEN(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter1,']]',']'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(@ColNameAsFilter1,1) = '"' AND RIGHT(@ColNameAsFilter1,1) = '"'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter1,'""','"'),2,LEN(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter1,'""','"'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(@ColNameAsFilter1,1) = '''' AND RIGHT(@ColNameAsFilter1,1) = ''''
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter1,'''''',''''),2,LEN(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter1,'''''',''''))-2)
                        ELSE @ColNameAsFilter1 END

    SET @ColNameAsFilter2 = CASE WHEN LEFT(@ColNameAsFilter2,1) = '[' AND RIGHT(@ColNameAsFilter2,1) = ']'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter2,']]',']'),2,LEN(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter2,']]',']'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(@ColNameAsFilter2,1) = '"' AND RIGHT(@ColNameAsFilter2,1) = '"'
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter2,'""','"'),2,LEN(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter2,'""','"'))-2)
                        WHEN LEFT(@ColNameAsFilter2,1) = '''' AND RIGHT(@ColNameAsFilter2,1) = ''''
                            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter2,'''''',''''),2,LEN(REPLACE(@ColNameAsFilter2,'''''',''''))-2)
                        ELSE @ColNameAsFilter2 END

    --====================================================
    -- Check that the first filter column name is valid
    IF @ColNameAsFilter1 <> '' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM sys.all_columns
                    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableSchema+'.'+@tableName)
                      AND name = @ColNameAsFilter1)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'Table %s.%s does not have a column %s.',
                        16,
                        1,
                        @tableSchema,
                        @tableName,
                        @ColNameAsFilter1)
            RETURN
        END

    --====================================================
    -- Check that the second filter column name is valid
    IF @ColNameAsFilter2 <> '' AND
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM sys.all_columns
                    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableSchema+'.'+@tableName)
                      AND name = @ColNameAsFilter2)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR (N'Table %s.%s does not have a column %s.',
                        16,
                        1,
                        @tableSchema,
                        @tableName,
                        @ColNameAsFilter2)
            RETURN
        END 


    --====================================================
    -- Construct & execute the dynamic SQL
    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)

    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + CHAR(13) +
        ' FROM [' + @tableSchema + '].['+ @tableName + ']' + CHAR(13) + 
        ' WHERE 1=1 '

    IF @ColNameAsFilter1 != ''
        SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + CHAR(13) + 
            ' AND ' + QUOTENAME(@ColNameAsFilter1) + ' = @ColFilter1VAL'

    IF @ColNameAsFilter2 != ''
        SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + CHAR(13) + 
            ' AND ' + QUOTENAME(@ColNameAsFilter2) + ' = @ColFilter2VAL'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand,
            N'@ColFilter1VAL nvarchar(75), @ColFilter2VAL nvarchar(75)', 
            @ColFilter1VAL, @ColFilter2VAL
END
```

Comment: Column `Altitude From Pressure` is not allowed? Drat!

Comment: @HABO I did say I liked the way you handled the columnList better. :) If  you don't object I'll "borrow" your idea to split the list.

Comment: @HABO this is nice to have some help on that issue, as it is very important for me, it is also first time for me to use functions so i found it esier to start with @ kenneth test, though both of those tests seems to be the same resultd as my initial test. (continuing in next comment)

Comment: @HABO ...with this SP above the only diffrence(which i could notes in my test).. is that it eliminates the problem of multiple quated columns, though i could not get results back to the c# code - ExecuteScalar(), and i think its because i am implementing it wrong (how to return value). so could you please post the code of implementation of the SP via a c# class ?. i think i made a mistake somehow the return value i get, is what i am assigning as the columns list (N'*' or N'col1, col2') i am using an `SqlParamList` passed to the data interaction section, so i think i am using wrong c# approach.

Comment: @AviaAfer - [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.100).aspx) returns only the first column of the first row of the result set. You want to use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.100).aspx) to retrieve the complete result set.

Comment: @HABO thanks . i only corrected passing the columnList from `("N'*'")` or `("'*'")` to ("*") so first test that was good did return as u said only first column, and i thought using different executer, so i now just need to go back to that test as i now get -1 at all variations of attempts , going to have some more tries (: cheers for your last comment

Comment: @AviaAfer - I've added some sample C# code to my answer. Untested, but looks moderately authentic.

Comment: now it works , and for it's simplicity and first test to pass back values as expected , i've 'harnessed' the return object via `DataAdapter` and field a `DataTable`. works also with set of commaSeparated values as a list of columnsNames.. and `*` as SELECT ALL , so it is absolutely a very very good candidate for this quiz as the correct Answer, really good solution !

Comment: on a related note - can such SP handle arbitrary set of filtering parameters? e.g. I have a bunch of conditions from UI that can use any field in a table and possibly not once

Comment: It would be a bit more complicated but you could pass them in as delimited strings just like the column list.  You would have to use the splitter function to break them out into a temp table, check each pair, etc and it would make building your dynamic SQL string a bit more complicated but it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to go down this path, here is a starting point.  It includes a *free* string splitting function.  And uses `NULL`s rather than empty strings to indicate unused filter columns.

```
create function dbo.SplitCSL( @CSL as NVarChar(4000) )
  -- Based on Jeff Moden's design.
  returns table
  with schemabinding as
  return
  with Digits as ( select Digit from ( values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9) ) as Digits( Digit ) ),
    Numbers as ( select ( ( Ten_3.Digit * 10 + Ten_2.Digit ) * 10 + Ten_1.Digit ) * 10 + Ten_0.Digit + 1 as Number
      from Digits as Ten_0 cross join Digits as Ten_1 cross join Digits as Ten_2 cross join Digits as Ten_3 ),
    cteTally(N) as ( select 0 union all select top ( DataLength( IsNull( @CSL, 1 ) ) ) 
      Row_Number() over ( order by ( select NULL ) ) from Numbers ),
    cteStart(N1) as ( select N + 1 from cteTally where Substring( @CSL, N, 1 ) = N',' OR N = 0 )
  select Item = Substring( @CSL, N1, IsNull( NullIf( CharIndex( N',', @CSL, N1 ), 0 ) - N1, 8000 ) )
    from cteStart;
go

create procedure [dbo].[SafeSqlSP_SelectGivenTableWithOptionalColFilter] 
  @ColumnList VarChar(75) = '*',
  @TableName SysName,
  @ColNameAsFilter1 VarChar(75) = NULL,
  @ColNameAsFilter2 VarChar(75) = NULL,
  @ColFilter1Val VarChar(75) = '',
  @ColFilter2Val VarChar(75) = ''       
as
  begin

  set nocount on;

  declare @Schema as SysName = 'dbo';

  -- Validate the table name.
  if not exists ( select 42 from Information_Schema.Tables where Table_Schema = @Schema and Table_Name = @TableName )
    begin
    RaIsError( '@TableName   does not reference a valid table or view.', 13, 0 );
    return;
    end;

  -- Validate and   QUOTENAME   the column list.
  declare @SelectList as NVarChar(1000);
  if @ColumnList = '*'
    set @SelectList = '*'
  else
    begin
    declare @Columns as Table ( ColumnName SysName );
    insert into @Columns
      select Item from dbo.SplitCSL( @ColumnList );
    if exists ( select 42 from @Columns as C left outer join
      Information_Schema.Columns as ISC on ISC.Table_Schema = @Schema and ISC.Table_Name = @TableName and ISC.Column_Name = C.ColumnName
      where ISC.Column_Name is NULL )
      begin
      RaIsError( '@ColumnList   references an invalid column in the table or view.', 13, 0 );
      return;
      end;
    -- Build a comma separated list ofquoted column names.
    select @SelectList = Stuff(
      ( select N',' + QuoteName( ColumnName ) from @Columns for XML path(''), type).value('.[1]', 'NVarChar(1000)' ),
      1, 1, '' );
    end;

  -- Validate the filter columns.
  if @ColNameAsFilter1 is not NULL and
    not exists ( select 42 from Information_Schema.Columns
      where Table_Schema = @Schema and Table_Name = @TableName and Column_Name = @ColNameAsFilter1 )
    begin
    RaIsError( '@ColNameAsFilter1   does not reference a valid column in the table or view.', 13, 0 );
    return;
    end;
  if @ColNameAsFilter2 is not NULL and
    not exists ( select 42 from Information_Schema.Columns
      where Table_Schema = @Schema and Table_Name = @TableName and Column_Name = @ColNameAsFilter2 )
    begin
    RaIsError( '@ColNameAsFilter2   does not reference a valid column in the table or view.', 13, 0 );
    return;
    end;

  -- Build the parameterized query.
  declare @SqlCommand as NVarChar(1000) =
    'select ' + @SelectList + ' from ' + QuoteName( @Schema ) + '.' + QuoteName( @TableName ) + case
    when @ColNameAsFilter1 is not NULL and @ColNameAsFilter2 is NULL
      then ' where ' + QuoteName( @ColNameAsFilter1 ) + ' = @ColFilter1Val'
    when @ColNameAsFilter1 is NULL and @ColNameAsFilter2 is not NULL
      then ' where ' + QuoteName( @ColNameAsFilter2 ) + ' = @ColFilter2Val'
    when @ColNameAsFilter1 is not NULL and @ColNameAsFilter2 is not NULL
      then ' where ' + QuoteName( @ColNameAsFilter1 ) + ' = @ColFilter1Val and ' + QuoteName( @ColNameAsFilter2 ) + ' = @ColFilter2Val'
    else ''
    end

  print 'SQL: ' + @SqlCommand; -- Debugging.

  declare @ParameterDefinitions as NVarChar(1000) = '@ColFilter1Val VarChar(75), @ColFilter2Val VarChar(75)';
  execute sp_ExecuteSql @SqlCommand, @ParameterDefinitions, @ColFilter1Val, @ColFilter2Val;

  end
go
```

C# code to invoke the procedure would look something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    // Connect to the database.
    sqlConnection.Open();

    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
    {
        // Set up the stored procedure call.
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SafeSqlSP_SelectGivenTableWithOptionalColFilter";
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnList", "ShoeSize");
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", "Employees");
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColNameAsFilter1 ", "ManagerId");
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColFilter1Val ", "42");

        // Execute the stored procedure.
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        // Process the results.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Debug.Print((string)reader["ShoeSize"]);
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: `@ColumnList   references an invalid column in the table or view`... getting your error reference at every test . with the other SP(@ Kenneth) test i did manage to pool back results via using Data adapter filling a data table so its fine now, so if you did not test  your Sp via passing an SqlParamList or something more real than strings though i should try more ... if you do have a clue for why i get this in your SP(i have implemented storing that stored procedure via its function, both are completed without errors in SSMS) so the only bug for my test is to do with how i pass parms in..

Comment: got it , when passing in "acolumnName" it works greate  Next test passes `string.Concate(StrColumn_A, ", ", StrColumn_B)` fails with erorr i wrote above

Comment: @AviaAfer - When I tested it in SSMS with `exec dbo.SafeSqlSP_SelectGivenTableWithOptionalColFilter @TableName = 'Things', @ColumnList = 'ThingId,ThingName,ThingId,ThingId', @ColNameAsFilter1 = 'ThingId', @ColFilter1Val = '2';` it worked correctly. I don't have time at the moment to test with an application.